# Microsoft Fakes code for Entity Framework

Tags: microsoft-fakes

I am working on Microsoft Fakes code to Fake the entities in DBcontext.I am facing an issue.
The AsNoTracking() method on Fake DBSet returns null.

eg:DBContext.Employee.AsNoTracking() returns null when Employee entity is faked.

Any solution for this problem will be really helpfull

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you overriding it to not return null? No? We can't be sure because you posted no code, but it seems likely you just included Fakes and hoped for the best. That's the only assumption we can make, for now.

Comment: @Magus.I have added the code in the post.

Comment: You should edit the question, not post an answer that isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code.The `GetEmployees()` returns an exception "Value is null". The error    occurs in `AsNoTracking()` method. But if I remove `AsNoTracking()`, the test method is working fine.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGetEmployeesList()
    {
        using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {
            ShimDbSet<Employee> EmployeeSet = new ShimDbSet<Employee>();
            ShimEntities dbShim = new ShimEntities();

            List<Employee> tempEmployeeList = GetEmployeeList();
            EmployeeSet.Bind(tempEmployeeList.AsQueryable());

            dbShim.EmployeeGet = () =>  {   return EmployeeSet.Instance;    };

            Employee employeeTest = new Employee()  {   DB = databaseShim.Instance  };

            List<EmployeeTransfer> employeeList = employeeTest.GetEmployees("TestEmployee");
            Assert.AreEqual(2, employeeList.Count);

        }
    }
public static List<Employee> GetEmployeeList()
    {
        List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>
        {
                new Employee
                {
                    EmployeeId = 1,
                    EmployeeName ="TestEmployee",
                },
                 new  Employee
                {
                    EmployeeId = 2,
                    EmployeeName ="TestEmp",
                }
        };
        return EmployeeList;
    }
public EmployeeData GetEmployees()
    {
        var query = from item in DB.Employee.AsNoTracking()
                        select item;
        var employeeList = query.ToList();

        return employeeList.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: This code makes no sense anyway, because GetEmployees takes a string above but not where you've declared it below. I don't see you shimming all instances of AsNoTracking(). Could that be the problem? Note that even if you do, you're just testing that Fakes works correctly, which it does.